# Retrieve a single Realm object using Primary key - Error : Invalid Object ID string must be 24 hex digits

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to get a single object using primary key but it never works and cannot figure out what I missed

My Realm data model is as follows

```
class Chapter : Object {
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var chapterID = 0
    @objc dynamic var bookmark =  0.0
    @objc dynamic var marked = false
    
    
    let notes = List<Notes>()
    
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "chapterID"
    }
} 


 func addNote(note: Note, chapterID: Int ) {
        
    objectWillChange.send()
 
    do {
  
      
let chapter = try Realm().object(ofType: Chapter.self, forPrimaryKey: "\(chapterID)")
//  code to append note 

}
catch let error {
      // Handle error
      print("Error in retrieving chapter no. \(chapterID)")
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

When I try to retrieve object by chapterID as primary key using  Realm().object(ofType:  forPrimaryKey:) or instance of Realm realm.object(ofType:forPrimaryKey:
I got the following error. e.g. for id 2

**Invalid Object ID string '2': must be 24 hex digits**

Thanks for any tips

Comment: I kinda know what's going on here but need to verify something. Can you open your Realm file with MongoDB Realm Studio and examine the Chapter object, looking at the column heading for the chapterID property? I want to know what type of property its showing. Be sure to open the correct Realm file as there could be several. Also, did you follow the getting started guide and/or change your Chapter model at any point?

Comment: Thanks it shows chapterID int(Primary key)

Comment: For clarity - the code causing the issue is not shown in the question. The code shown is *writing* to realm and the issue was *reading* from realm.

Comment: right, the code is first retrieve (read)an object then append (write) to object's notes list a note  ..  the error was in retrieve line, that's why I did not include write code because there is no issue in it, once it successfully retrieve the object, writing would be straightforward

Comment: Well, my comment was totally unclear in an attempt to add clarity. lol.  I was saying that this `"\(chapterID)")` casts the chapterID (an Int) to a String. IF the data stored in realm was a String, reading it would work. More importantly though (off topic) using an int as a primary key has some drawbacks and you may want to consider using a UUID or and ObjectID property type as the primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chapterID` is an `Int` so you shouldn't be passing a `String` when you try to fetch the `Chapter`. Just pass in an integer value.

```
let chapter = try Realm().object(ofType: Chapter.self, forPrimaryKey: chapterID)
```

Depending on which Realm you are using, I would recommend the newer syntax:

```
class Chapter: Object {
    @Persisted var title = ""
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var chapterID = 0
    @Persisted var bookmark =  0.0
    @Persisted var marked = false
}
```

Comment: It works now,  thanks